# Remove leading zeros when reading a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, leading-zero

I have a CSV file that looks something like this -

```
    Location ID      Location Name
        3543459      A
         20541       B
          C320       C
           ...       ..
```

When I read the file using `pd.read_csv`, I get something like this -

```
Location ID      Location Name
   03543459      A
   0020541       B
   000C320       C
       ...       ..
```

How to avoid leading zeros? I did some research, all the questions I could ifind were based on producing the leading zeros in the df.

Comment: `df["Location ID"].str.lstrip("0")`?

Comment: If you make `Location ID` an integer column, they'll disappear automatically. Is `Location ID` supposed to be integer or string (or Categorical)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use post processing by [`str.lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
df['Location ID'] = df['Location ID'].str.lstrip('0')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had mixed type below line worked ..

```
 df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x:x.lstrip('0') if type(x) == str else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Location ID'] = df['Location ID'].apply(lambda x: x.lstrip('0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with more complex strings (e.g., `'AB00003423'`), you can use `Series.str.extract()` and a regular expression:

`extractedNumbers = df.ID_col.str.extract('^[A-Z]+0+([0-9]+)$')`

This will return a column of whatever is inside the parentheses (or "capture group(s)") of the regular expression.

Normally a dataframe is returned with 1 column per capture group, use `expand=False` to return a Series instead.